# Chart Js Число и день недели

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Нужно сделать так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получилось только так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос как добавить "Пн, Вт, Ср, Чт и т.д." ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно в labels передать массив вместо каждой строки, которую вы передаете сейчас.

```
labels: [['10', 'пн'], ['11', 'вт'], ['12', 'ср'], ['13', 'чт'], ['14', 'пт'], ['15', 'сб'], ['16', 'вс']],
```

```js
const options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [
      ['10', "пн"],
      ['10', "вт"],
      ['10', "ср"],
      ['10', "чт"],
      ['10', "пт"],
      ['10', "сб"]
    ],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }, ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="170"></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А подскажите еще пожалуйста, как можно отдельно их стилизовать. Пн, Вт, Ср - сделать другой шрифт и размер?

Comment: @ИльяРаевский Как отдельно стилизовать их я уже не смогу подсказать